# How to return values entered in a dynamic table textboxes if there is an error on form submit

Tags: php

Coud somebody please help me. I have a textbox name "txtremise" found in a dynamic table where user enter a discount %. I am trying to return the values entered in each textbox if there is an error during the form submit.

Lets say, there are 3 rows with 3 textboxes in the table. A user enter 5, 10, 15 respectively in each textbox. Let's say there was an error upon submitting the form, i need the values 5, 10, 15 back in their respective textboxes. Can somebody please assist?

Here is how i generate the textboxes:

```
    <?php
    while($iArticles < count($listeArticlePourUnDossier))
    {
    ?>  
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo ($listeArticlePourUnDossier[$iArticles]['ARTICLE_NOM']); ?></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="txtremise[]" id="txtremise_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" class="remise" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtremise'];" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php       
    $iArticles++;
    }
    ?>
```

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i=0;
while($iArticles < count($listeArticlePourUnDossier))
{
?>  
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo ($listeArticlePourUnDossier[$iArticles]['ARTICLE_NOM']); ?></td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['txtremise'][$i])){ echo $_POST['txtremise_'][$iArticles];}?>" name="txtremise[]" id="txtremise_<?php echo $iArticles; ?>" class="remise" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtremise'];" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php       
$i++;
$iArticles++;
}
?>
```

You still have that value in either $_POST or $_GET so check if the key is isset then echo the value. So all you need is to add value in your input

Comment: how..im not sure how

Comment: just try my code and check will it work or not i had added value attribute in input tag